# SQL Server 2019 (Centos 8) Non-Yielding Scheduler

Tags: centos, sqlserver

We are running SQL Server 2019 (Linux) CU4 with the following server specs:

- OS: Centos 8
- RAM: 32GB
- HDD: 1TB SSD
- CPU: 8 Core I-7
- SQL: Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU4) (KB4548597) - 15.0.4033.1 (X64) Standard Edition (64-bit) on Linux (CentOS Linux 8 (Core))

The SQL server becomes unresponsive after heavy loads (it appears) and has the following in the SQLDump file after a crash...

```
2020-04-09 02:38:11.48 spid12s     AppDomain 3 (mssqlsystemresource.dbo[runtime].2) is marked for unload due to memory pressure.
2020-04-09 02:38:11.48 spid12s     AppDomain 3 (mssqlsystemresource.dbo[runtime].2) unloaded.
2020-04-09 10:09:43.60 spid31s     AppDomain 2 (master.sys[runtime].1) is marked for unload due to memory pressure.
2020-04-09 10:09:43.61 spid31s     AppDomain 2 (master.sys[runtime].1) unloaded.
2020-04-10 11:52:15.26 Backup      Database backed up. Database: readyalert, creation date(time): 2020/02/11(08:19:22), pages dumped: 190987, first LSN: 67110:336:1, last LSN: 67110:360:1, number of dump devices: 1, device information: (FILE=1, TYPE=DISK: {'/var/opt/mssql/backup/readyalert_prod.BAK'}). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2020-04-10 11:52:15.28 Backup      BACKUP DATABASE successfully processed 190746 pages in 4.842 seconds (307.765 MB/sec).
2020-04-12 00:00:02.54 spid59      [8]. Feature Status: PVS: 0. CTR: 0. ConcurrentPFSUpdate: 1.
2020-04-12 00:00:12.34 spid59      DBCC CHECKDB (readyalert) executed by NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE found 0 errors and repaired 0 errors. Elapsed time: 0 hours 0 minutes 9 seconds.  Internal database snapshot has split point LSN = 00010627:00010e78:0001 and first LSN = 00010627:00010e68:0001.
2020-04-15 11:12:58.53 spid59      AppDomain 4 (mssqlsystemresource.dbo[runtime].3) created.
2020-04-15 11:16:28.21 spid88      AppDomain 5 (master.sys[runtime].4) created.
2020-04-15 14:39:02.71 Server      Using 'dbghelp.dll' version '4.0.5'
2020-04-15 14:39:02.76 Server      ***Unable to get thread context for spid 0
2020-04-15 14:39:02.76 Server      * *******************************************************************************
2020-04-15 14:39:02.76 Server      *
2020-04-15 14:39:02.76 Server      * BEGIN STACK DUMP:
2020-04-15 14:39:02.76 Server      *   04/15/20 14:39:02 spid 384
2020-04-15 14:39:02.76 Server      *
2020-04-15 14:39:02.76 Server      * Non-yielding Scheduler
2020-04-15 14:39:02.76 Server      *
2020-04-15 14:39:02.76 Server      * *******************************************************************************
2020-04-15 14:39:02.77 Server      Stack Signature for the dump is 0x0000000000000338
```

Any help would be appreciated as we tried updating to the latest CU4 and the problem still persists.

Comment: "memory pressure"... how much swap do you have? How much physical memory was in use when you got this crash? How much swap was in use? What else was running/busy (what did `uptime` tell you about the load average)?

Answer (score 0):

For us solution was disable database synchronization between nodes. Microsoft probably starts putting transactions to sync data and it locks over with main server transactions, as they probably run in separate threads. Thus racing condition and eventually Non-yielding

on latest 15.0.4043.16-4

```
2020-07-06 13:04:01.87 Server      Using 'dbghelp.dll' version '4.0.5'
2020-07-06 13:04:01.96 Server      ***Unable to get thread context for spid 0
2020-07-06 13:04:01.96 Server      * *******************************************************************************
2020-07-06 13:04:01.96 Server      *
2020-07-06 13:04:01.96 Server      * BEGIN STACK DUMP:
2020-07-06 13:04:01.97 Server      *   07/06/20 13:04:01 spid 400
2020-07-06 13:04:01.97 Server      *
2020-07-06 13:04:01.97 Server      * Non-yielding Scheduler
2020-07-06 13:04:01.97 Server      *
2020-07-06 13:04:01.97 Server      * *******************************************************************************
2020-07-06 13:04:01.98 Server      Stack Signature for the dump is 0x0000000000000246
2020-07-06 13:04:55.94 Server      DumpCallbackHk::CreateCabFile: at 2206 g_CabDdfFile file is null, normally because no collectors added any files, exiting
2020-07-06 13:04:55.94 Server      DumpCallbackHk::CollectFiles: at 594 failed at CreateCabFile with error: 0x80004005
2020-07-06 13:04:57.21 Server      External dump process return code 0x20000001.
External dump process returned no errors.
2020-07-06 13:04:57.21 Server      Process 0:0:0 (0x4298) Worker 0x0000001D4CE46160 appears to be non-yielding on Scheduler 0. Thread creation time: 13238513480709. Approx Thread CPU Used: kernel 130 ms, user 7180 ms. Process Utilization 16%. System Idle 0%. Interval: 70006 ms.
...
```